Red-Black tree implemention in C++
I've been practicing CLRS book's algorithms. To be more cpecific - I tried to write Red-Black Tree using STL, to train my C++ programming skills. How you can see, they're not good enough. I've got some problems of writing DeleteNode function. It seems like node's replacement doesn't bound correctly to the Parent node. I've used  Program leaves segmentation fault error:
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
RBTree.h
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

#ifndef CLRSC___RBTREE_H
#define CLRSC___RBTREE_H

enum class Colour{
    Red,
    Black,
    DoubleBlack
};

struct Node{
    int Data;
    Colour colour;
    shared_ptr<Node> Left = nullptr;
    shared_ptr<Node> Right = nullptr;
    weak_ptr<Node> Parent;
};


class RBTree {
public:
    shared_ptr<Node> Root = nullptr;

    void RotateLeft(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void RotateRight(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void FixInsertRBTree(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void FixDeleteRBTree(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void InsertValue(int val);
    void InsertNode(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void DeleteNode(const int data);
    void Transplant(shared_ptr<Node> u, shared_ptr<Node> v);
    shared_ptr<Node> MinValueNode(shared_ptr<Node> node);
    shared_ptr<Node> MaxValueNode(shared_ptr<Node> node);
    shared_ptr<Node> Find(const int data);

    void SetColour(shared_ptr<Node>& node, Colour colour);
    Colour GetColour(const shared_ptr<Node>& node);

    bool DelCase1(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    void DelCase2(shared_ptr<Node>& node);
    bool DelCase3(shared_ptr<Node>& parent,shared_ptr<Node>& pointer );
    bool DelCase4(shared_ptr<Node>& parent,shared_ptr<Node>& pointer );

};


#endif //CLRSC___RBTREE_H

RBTree.cpp
#include "RBTree.h"
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>


void RBTree::InsertValue(int val) {
    shared_ptr<Node> NewNode = make_shared<Node>();
    NewNode->Data = val;
    NewNode->colour = Colour::Red;
    InsertNode(NewNode);
    FixInsertRBTree(NewNode);
}

void RBTree::InsertNode(shared_ptr<Node> &node) {
    if (this->Root == nullptr) {
        // If the tree is empty, set the new node as the root
        this->Root = node;
        return;
    }

    shared_ptr<Node> current = this->Root;
    shared_ptr<Node> parent = nullptr;

    // Traverse the tree to find the correct position for insertion
    while (current != nullptr) {
        parent = current;
        if (node->Data < current->Data) {
            current = current->Left;
        } else if (node->Data > current->Data) {
            current = current->Right;
        } else {
            // Handle case where node with same value exists (if needed)
            // You might want to decide what to do if a duplicate is found
            // For this example, let's not allow duplicates
            return;
        }
    }

    // Insert node based on comparison with parent
    if (node->Data < parent->Data) {
        parent->Left = node;
    } else {
        parent->Right = node;
    }

    // Set parent of the newly inserted node
    node->Parent = parent;
}


Colour RBTree::GetColour(const shared_ptr<Node>& node) {
    if(node == nullptr)
        return Colour::Black;
    return node->colour;
}

void RBTree::SetColour(shared_ptr<Node>& node, Colour colour) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        node->colour = colour;
    }
}

void RBTree::RotateLeft(shared_ptr<Node> &node) {
    shared_ptr<Node> RightChild = node->Right;
    node->Right = RightChild->Left;

    if(node->Right != nullptr)
        node->Right->Parent = node;

    RightChild->Parent = node->Parent;

    if(node->Parent.lock() == nullptr)
        this->Root = RightChild;
    else if(node == node->Parent.lock()->Left)
        node->Parent.lock()->Left = RightChild;
    else
        node->Parent.lock()->Right = RightChild;

    RightChild->Left = node;
    node->Parent = RightChild;
}


void RBTree::RotateRight(shared_ptr<Node> &node) {
    shared_ptr<Node> LeftChild = node->Left;
    node->Left = LeftChild->Right;

    if(node->Left != nullptr)
        node->Left->Parent = node;

    LeftChild->Parent = node->Parent;

    if(node->Parent.lock() == nullptr)
        this->Root = LeftChild;
    else if(node == node->Parent.lock()->Left)
        node->Parent.lock()->Left = LeftChild;
    else
        node->Parent.lock()->Right = LeftChild;

    LeftChild->Right = node;
    node->Parent = LeftChild;

}


void RBTree::FixInsertRBTree(shared_ptr<Node> &node) {
    while (node != this->Root && GetColour(node->Parent.lock()) == Colour::Red) {
        auto parent = node->Parent.lock();
        auto grandparent = parent->Parent.lock();

        if (parent == grandparent->Left) {
            auto uncle = grandparent->Right;

            if (GetColour(uncle) == Colour::Red) {
                // Case 1: Uncle is red
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(uncle, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(grandparent, Colour::Red);
                node = grandparent; // Move up to grandparent
            } else {
                // Case 2: Uncle is black and node is a right child
                if (node == parent->Right) {
                    node = parent;
                    RotateLeft(node);
                    // Update parent and grandparent after rotation
                    parent = node->Parent.lock();
                    grandparent = parent->Parent.lock();
                }

                // Case 3: Uncle is black and node is a left child
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(grandparent, Colour::Red);
                RotateRight(grandparent);
            }
        } else {
            // Symmetric cases for right subtree (mirrored)
            auto uncle = grandparent->Left;

            if (GetColour(uncle) == Colour::Red) {
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(uncle, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(grandparent, Colour::Red);
                node = grandparent;
            } else {
                if (node == parent->Left) {
                    node = parent;
                    RotateRight(node);
                    parent = node->Parent.lock();
                    grandparent = parent->Parent.lock();
                }
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(grandparent, Colour::Red);
                RotateLeft(grandparent);
            }
        }
    }

    // Ensure root is black
    SetColour(this->Root, Colour::Black);
}


void RBTree::FixDeleteRBTree(shared_ptr<Node> &node) {
    while (node != this->Root && GetColour(node) == Colour::Black) {
        auto parent = node->Parent.lock();

        if (node == parent->Left) {
            shared_ptr<Node> sibling = parent->Right;

            if (GetColour(sibling) == Colour::Red) {
                // Case 1: Sibling is red
                SetColour(sibling, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Red);
                RotateLeft(parent);
                sibling = parent->Right;
            }

            if (GetColour(sibling->Left) == Colour::Black &&
                GetColour(sibling->Right) == Colour::Black) {
                // Case 2: Sibling and its children are black
                SetColour(sibling, Colour::Red);
                node = parent;
            } else {
                if (GetColour(sibling->Right) == Colour::Black) {
                    // Case 3: Sibling's right child is black
                    SetColour(sibling->Left, Colour::Black);
                    SetColour(sibling, Colour::Red);
                    RotateRight(sibling);
                    sibling = parent->Right;
                }

                // Case 4: Sibling's right child is red
                SetColour(sibling, GetColour(parent));
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(sibling->Right, Colour::Black);
                RotateLeft(parent);
                node = this->Root; // Exit loop
            }
        } else {
            // Symmetric cases for right child
            shared_ptr<Node> sibling = parent->Left;

            if (GetColour(sibling) == Colour::Red) {
                // Case 1: Sibling is red
                SetColour(sibling, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Red);
                RotateRight(parent);
                sibling = parent->Left;
            }

            if (GetColour(sibling->Right) == Colour::Black &&
                GetColour(sibling->Left) == Colour::Black) {
                // Case 2: Sibling and its children are black
                SetColour(sibling, Colour::Red);
                node = parent;
            } else {
                if (GetColour(sibling->Left) == Colour::Black) {
                    // Case 3: Sibling's left child is black
                    SetColour(sibling->Right, Colour::Black);
                    SetColour(sibling, Colour::Red);
                    RotateLeft(sibling);
                    sibling = parent->Left;
                }

                // Case 4: Sibling's left child is red
                SetColour(sibling, GetColour(parent));
                SetColour(parent, Colour::Black);
                SetColour(sibling->Left, Colour::Black);
                RotateRight(parent);
                node = this->Root; // Exit loop
            }
        }
    }

    SetColour(node, Colour::Black);
}


void RBTree::DeleteNode(int data)
{
    shared_ptr<Node> node = Find(data);
    if(node == nullptr) return;

    shared_ptr<Node> replacement;
    if (node->Left != nullptr && node->Right != nullptr){
        replacement = MinValueNode(node->Right);
       if (node == this->Root) {
            this->Root = replacement;
            this->Root->Parent.lock() = nullptr;
        }
        node.reset();
        node = replacement;
        return;
    }

    replacement = (node->Left != nullptr) ? node->Left : node->Right;
    if(replacement != nullptr)
        replacement->Parent = node->Parent.lock();

    if(node != this->Root){

    shared_ptr<Node> parent = node->Parent.lock();
    if(node == parent->Left)
        parent->Left = replacement;
    else
        parent->Right = replacement;
    if(GetColour(node) == Colour::Black)
        FixDeleteRBTree(replacement);
    }
    else{
        this->Root = replacement;
    }

    node.reset();
}



shared_ptr<Node> RBTree::MinValueNode(shared_ptr<Node> node) {
    while (node->Left != nullptr)
    {
        node = node->Left;
    }
    return node;
}

shared_ptr<Node> RBTree::MaxValueNode(shared_ptr<Node> node)
{
    shared_ptr<Node> current = node;
    while (current && current->Right != nullptr)
    {
        current = current->Right;
    }
    return current;
}

shared_ptr<Node> RBTree::Find(const int data){
    shared_ptr<Node> current = Root;

    while (current != nullptr){
        if (data < current->Data)
            current = current->Left;
        else if (data > current->Data)
            current = current->Right;
        else
            return current;
    }
    return nullptr;
}



Test.cpp

#include "RBTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

void inorderTraversal(shared_ptr<Node> node) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        inorderTraversal(node->Left);
        std::cout << node->Data << "(";
        if (node->colour == Colour::Red) {
            std::cout << "Red) ";
        } else if (node->colour == Colour::Black) {
            std::cout << "Black) ";
        } else if (node->colour == Colour::DoubleBlack) {
            std::cout << "DoubleBlack) ";
        }
        inorderTraversal(node->Right);
    }
}

int main() {
    RBTree tree;

    // Insert nodes into the tree
    tree.InsertValue(10);
    tree.InsertValue(20);
    tree.InsertValue(30);
    tree.InsertValue(15);
    tree.InsertValue(5);

    // Delete a node
    tree.DeleteNode(20);

    // Search for nodes
    int searchData = 15;
    shared_ptr<Node> foundNode = tree.Find(searchData);
    assert(foundNode != nullptr);  // Assertion should pass if node is found

    std::cout << "Inorder Traversal after Insertions: ";
    inorderTraversal(tree.Root);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Inorder Traversal after Deletion of 20: ";
    inorderTraversal(tree.Root);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Found node with value " << searchData << std::endl;

    std::cout << "All tests passed!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Your code asserts here  assert(foundNode != nullptr);

@Jabberwocky, So my code is clean?

Yes it is. The test was wrong.

FWIW: Usually, the Node class is not supposed to be exposed to the user, it's implementation details. The user only wants to manipulates values directly. For example if you take a look at std::list, std::map (which is often implemented as a red-black tree by the way) and so on... they don't expose the nodes in the interface (okay, std::map does since C++17 :D).
